# Servidor FTP público para probar código

Tags: python, ftp

Necesito un servidor FTP sólo para probar un código en Python que sube archivos.  Encontré: Test.Rebex.Net (https://test.rebex.net/) pero parece que no está funcionando.  Comparto el código por si a alguien más le sirve.  Es Python 2.7

```
import ftplib

session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.dlptest.com','dlpuser@dlptest.com','fLDScD4Ynth0p4OJ6bW6qCxjh') # Abre la sesión
filename = 'delete_file.sh'                                                               # Fichero a subir
file = open(filename,'rb')                                                                # Abre el fichero
session.storbinary(('STOR ' + filename), file)                                            # Lo sube
file.close()                                                                              # Cierra el fichero
session.quit()                                                                            # Cierra la sesión
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario abulatia pero usando anonymous como usuario y contraseña devuelve este error: ftplib.error_perm: 553 Could not create file.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias abulafia.  Efectivamente ese servidor está funcionando.  Si querés poné tu comentario como respuesta así lo tildo.

Comment: No deberías haber editado la pregunta para poner la solución, pues entonces ya no es consistente con lo que preguntabas. De todas formas posiblemente la cierren

Answer (score -2, accepted):

El servidor ftp `test.rebex.net` no admite subidas, pues es de solo lectura como indica en su [readme](ftp://demo:password@test.rebex.net/readme.txt):

> Only read access is allowed and the FTP download speed is limited to 16KBps.

Uno que sí lo admite es `ftp.dlptest.com`, pero para evitar abusos:

- Elimina cada media hora lo que se haya subido
- Cambia frecuentemente las credenciales para conexión.

Puedes ver las credenciales activas aquí: https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/ (estaban funcionando a fecha 2019-07-04)

Comment: ¿ En verdad consideras que esta pregunta es adecuada para el sitio y merece una respuesta ?

Comment: @Trauma Si es adecuada o no, no lo tengo claro, la verdad. He leido discusiones varias sobre si el sitio es sólo para preguntas de programación, o bien de informática en general. En cuanto a si merece una respuesta, creo que sí puede ser útil a quien necesite un servidor ftp para pruebas, pues para responder he tenido que hacer pruebas varias hasta dar con uno que funcionaba para upload, y esto puede ahorrar trabajo a otros. De otro modo no habría respondido :-)

Comment: En mi opinión, le has ahorrado una búsqueda en Google y algún intento de conexión. Igualmente según mi criterio, pide opiniones. Mi voto para cerrar en consecuencia ya lo tiene.